# vector<class> with private constructor

Tags: c++, vector, containers, private

I have the following situation: a class NoEntry contains data which can be inspected by the outside world, but the outside world is not allowed, in any way, to create those objects. Such a class looks like this:

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_NOENTRY_
#define INCLUDED_NOENTRY_

#include <string>

class NoEntry
{
    std::string d_name;
    size_t d_area = 0;
    size_t d_date = 0;

    public:
        std::string const &name() const;
        size_t area() const;
        size_t date() const;

    private:
        NoEntry(NoEntry const &other) = default;
        NoEntry() = default;
        NoEntry(std::string const &name, size_t area, size_t date);
};

#endif
```

Using NoEntry objects is a privilege of certain classes, declared as friends of NoEntry. So the class contains friend declarations:

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_NOENTRY_
#define INCLUDED_NOENTRY_

#include <string>

class NoEntry
{
    friend class PrivilegedOne;
    friend class PrivilegedTwo;

    std::string d_name;
    size_t d_area = 0;
    size_t d_date = 0;

    public:
        std::string const &name() const;
        size_t area() const;
        size_t date() const;

    private:
        NoEntry(NoEntry const &other) = default;
        NoEntry() = default;
        NoEntry(std::string const &name, size_t area, size_t date);
};

#endif
```

I have designed the following PrivilegedOne interface:

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_PRIVILEGEDONE_
#define INCLUDED_PRIVILEGEDONE_

#include <iosfwd>
#include <vector>

#include "../noentry/noentry.h"

class PrivilegedOne
{
    std::vector<NoEntry> d_noEntry;

    public:
        PrivilegedOne(std::string const &fname);

    private:
        NoEntry nextEntry(std::istream &in);    // empty name: all were read
};

#endif
```

Its member nextEntry is a simple one: it reads the data from file, and returns a NoEntry object.

```
//#define XERR
#include "privilegedone.ih"

NoEntry PrivilegedOne::nextEntry(istream &in)
{
    NoEntry ret;

    in >> ret.d_name >> ret.d_area >> ret.d_date;

    if (not in)                         // no more NoEntries: ensure
        ret.d_name.clear();             // that d_name is empty

    return ret;
}
```

PrvilegedOne's constructor must read all the NoEntry objects and must store them in d_noEntry. Here is its original implementation:

```
//#define XERR
#include "privilegedone.ih"

PrivilegedOne::PrivilegedOne(string const &fname)
{
    ifstream in{ fname };

    while (true)
    {
        NoEntry next = nextEntry(in); 

        if (next.name().empty())
            break;

        d_noEntry.push_back(next);          // Not working
    }
}
```

The "Not working" comment is the line that is causing all the problems.

Why doesn't the statement do its job?
Without modifying anything in the class NoEntry, but merely concentrating on PrivilegedOne: what must be done to allow objects of this class to store NoEntry objects in its d_noEntry vector?

I think I should redesign the definition of d_noEntry. And then I'll only have to modify the line with the "not working" comment.

But I am not sure how.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an error at compile time or at run time?

Comment: It's not working because the vector is not allowed to create instances of its own element type.

Comment: `friend class std::vector<NoEntry>;` and a comment asking for forgiveness to your fellow colleagues for such a ill-suited design.

Comment: What does "causing all the problems" mean?

Comment: If all constructors of your class are `private`, then only member functions of your class (including `static` members) or `friend`s of the class can create instances of it.    To push or move instances of that class into a `std::vector`, then that vector class will need to be declared as a friend.  `std::push_back()`, among other things, uses a constructor of your class to add an element, but may call other functions to do that job).

Comment: @YSC There is no guarantee whatsoever that it will work. The function that tries to create the vector elements is not necessarily a member of `std::vector`. The job can be delegated to a different class or to a standalone function. It may work with one standard library implementation and break with another one.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. You're 100% right. The meaningful part of my comment was more the second one that the first ;)

Answer (score 2):

As @"n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m." commented, you can't create a std::vector of this type that will work with any possible implementation.

The [push_back() method of std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) takes a reference, but needs to copy the object to the new location.

What you can do is to create a wrapper and `friend class` it.
Implement that class like:

```
#pragma once
#include "NoEntry.h"

class NoEntryWrapper {
    NoEntry content;
    friend class NoEntry;
public:
    NoEntryWrapper() = default;
    NoEntryWrapper(const NoEntryWrapper &) = default;
    NoEntryWrapper(const NoEntry & content) : content(content) {}
    NoEntry &getContent() { return content; }
};
```

Modify `NoEntry` implementation:

```
// do not include "NoEntryWrapper.h"
class NoEntryWrapper; // forward declare it

class NoEntry
{
    friend class PrivilegedOne;
    friend class PrivilegedTwo;
    friend class NoEntryWrapper; // this is new

    // ... your original code ...

    NoEntry(const NoEntryWrapper &wrapper);
    // make NoEntryWrapper implicitly convertable back to NoEntry
}
```

and define the newly added contructor in the `.cpp` file

```
#include "NoEntryWrapper.h"
NoEntry::NoEntry(const NoEntryWrapper &wrapper) : NoEntry(wrapper.content) {}
```

And also modify `PrivilegedOne` class:
Replace `std::vector<NoEntry> d_noEntry;` with `std::vector<NoEntryWrapper> d_noEntry;`.

You can use the vector now as you excepted.

Example code:

```
        std::vector<NoEntryWrapper> d_noEntry;
        d_noEntry.push_back(NoEntry("test", 0, 1));
        NoEntry test = d_noEntry[0];
        std::cout << test.d_name << " " << test.d_area << std::endl;

        d_noEntry[0] = NoEntry("other", 5, 5);
        d_noEntry[0].getContent().d_name = "other (name changed)";
        // this is the only drawback - you need a getter to access it this way
        NoEntry other = d_noEntry[0];
        std::cout << other.d_name << " " << other.d_area << std::endl;

// Output:
//test 0
//other (name changed) 5
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't the statement do its job?

Because `NoEntry` does not meet the [CopyInsertable requirements of `push_back`](http://NoEntry%20does%20not%20meet%20the%20CopyInsertable%20requirements%20of%20push_back.), which means, `vector::push_back` needs at least a public copy constructor for the items stored. `push_back` will need to copy items into the internal storage array, and copy again when it comes to reallocating storage.

One way of working around this limitation is not storing `NoEntry` objects in the vector, but pointers or `std::unique_ptr<NoEntry>` items. The latter has only [`MoveConstructible` and `MoveAssignable` requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), but not `CopyInsertable`.

Comment: But using a vector of pointers won't work as the noEntry object is temporal so the vector would be adding a pointer to undefined

Comment: @programmer2: it is pretty obvious that the example of the OP was incomplete for the sake of simplicity, and that `d_noEntry` will have a longer lifetime in the real code.

Comment: @DocBrown what  OPforgot to mention is that only the `// Not working` line and d_NoEntry should be changed, according to the homework exercise of the course. Your second tip really is the solution: change to `std::unique_ptr<NoEntry>` items. A bit sad stumbling on the solution, I was only trying to google what `//define XERR` was. OP also could've been more clear this being a homework exercise.

Comment: @Keipi: if you are correct and it is a homework exercise, the OP should have mentioned that, too.